# Converting string to JSON type for Postgres while loading using AWS Glue JOB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am trying to load data via AWS Glue JOB to RDS table (Postgres)

Other fields are fine but I have a field in Postgres as `json` and and mapped field in AWS Glue Catalog is of string type.

How can I convert string to json type as I am getting following error while JOB runs

> "ERROR: column "propertylist_json" is of type json but expression is of type character varying"

Comment: If it contains valid json, you can simply cas it, `propertylist_json::jsonb` but without the actual code this is really difficult to answer

Comment: catalog table has propertylist_json as string and RDS postgres has as json field 'propertylist_json'

is it possible in Glue job script to cast?

Comment: As I wrote: without the actual code that you are running, this is impossible to answer

Comment: this is the mapping in auto generated script
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("id", "long", "id", "string"), ("type", "string", "type", "string"), ("name", "string", "name", "string"), ("source", "string", "source", "string"), ("latt", "string", "latt", "double"), ("long", "string", "long", "double"), ("propertylist_json", "string", "propertylist_json", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")